# Real Analysis: If $X$ is the set of all mappings of $N$ into $\{0,1\}$, then $X$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis

For each $A\subset N$, let $1_A : N \to \{0,1\}$ be defined by $1_A (n) = 1$ if $n \in A$, and $1_A (n) = 0$ if $n \notin A$. It is easy to check that the map $A \to 1_A$ is a bijective map of $\mathscr{P}(N)$ onto $X$, so it follows from the last theorem that $X$ is uncountable.

I really cannot understand the above proof to the corollary in the title. Particularly, I cannot understand the link between $A \to 1_A$ and bijective map of $\mathscr{P}$ onto $X$. Could you please explain in more detailed and understandable way? Thank you in advance!

P.S. The corollary is taken from "Mathematical Analysis: An Introduction" by Andrew Browder at page $8$ (Chapter $1.3.$ Infinite Sets).

P.S.S. $\mathscr{P}(N)$ is a power set of $N$, i.e., the set of all subsets of a set $N$.

Comment: The function $G:\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\to \{\text{functions }\Bbb N\to \{0,1\}\}$, $G(A)=1_A$ is a bijective function. I.e.: 1) for all $A,B\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $A\ne B$, $1_A\ne 1_B$; 2) for all $f:\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$ there is some $S\subseteq \Bbb N$ such that $f=1_S$.

Comment: the link is that if you show that $\{0,1\}$ is an uncountable set, you show that it is in bijection with an uncountable set (analogous to showing a set is countable you show that it is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$). Here that uncountable set is $\mathscr{P} (\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: @Rick I think you meant $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, because if you show that $\{0,1\}$ is uncountable you also swoh that $0=1$.

Comment: I am using the notation of the O.P.

Comment: @Cacari Does it help to clarify your doubt?